# Custom Require Forms in NS decls?

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to insert custom forms into Clojure's ns declarations?

For example,

```
(ns
  (:refer-my-library :exclude [something])
  (:require [x :as y]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that? Depending on your answer, ns metadata might be a better alternative:

```
(ns foo {:my-data [:something]})
(meta (the-ns 'foo)) ;;=> {:my-data [:something]}
```

Comment: Well I have groupings of require forms, depending on context, that I need to always copy and paste which is error prone.  I'd rather be able to (refer my.co.web) instead.  It would be awesome if I could refer "out" of a namespace the way you can in racket.  And especially with clojurescript disallowing refer all, my ns form is always the ugliest and one screaming at me to refactor into lib fns.

Answer (score 0):

No. Well, you shouldn't. While the keywords like `:require` and `:refer-clojure` represent real functions or macros, they are assumed to be in the `clojure.core` namespace.

See the [definition of ns](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5821), where it converts the directive `:require` into `clojure.core/require`.

```
(symbol "clojure.core" (clojure.core/name kname))
```